# Convert 15 minute kW readings to a monthly kWh total

Tags: power, energy, calculation

I have metering data (kW) in 15 minute intervals that I am trying to get a monthly kWh total for...
I simply summed the entire kW range, then multiplied it by hours in the month 745 (total number of readings 2,981/4). This seemed too simple though and now I'm just confused after looking at it for so long.  Is this correct? Or is there more to it?

Comment: You could also interpolate between datapoints and use an integral instead of a sum. It depends what you would expect to happen between the measured data points.

Comment: Is the 15 minute metering kW data an average value of kW over the preceding 15 minute period or is it something else?

Comment: yes it is a mean kW of the previous 15 minute interval.  It shows min/max values also but I am ignoring those for basic Energy  calculations

Comment: Another way of doing is integrating or find area under power curve plotted over time with each power point. Assume linearity between each point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the power is constant for every 15 minute interval. You get

$$E[n] = P[n] * 0.25~\text{h}$$ where \$ P[n] \$ is in kW and \$ E[n] \$ in kWh

$$Total Energy = \sum_{i=1}^n {E[n]} $$

Where n is the number of 15-minute readings in a month (n will vary from month to month)

Comment: Ok.  Thank you.  Are you using h to stand for TOTAL hours in the month or are you using h just to show unit hour in that calculation? My original calculation was way off and using your top one is looking very accurate.  I assume this is the correct one to use, since it is 15 minute data I don't need to multiply by total hours if I add it all up with P[n].

Comment: I used h to mean "unit hour in that calculation.

Comment: @Ben I fixed the h, it's a bit of a hassle without the siunitx package but ~\text{} works okayish.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is correct, although 365 days /12m * 24h  = 730 hrs per month, not 745.
Even 31 days only has 744h unless you are thinking of the extra hour in the fall from DLS. or maybe you double-counted the Midnight Hour ha...

Time of Use (TOU) costs are common everywhere, so your actual cost may depend, but your total kWh of consumption should be correct.  Our Electrical provider Alectra gives all these graphs online by the minutes to a year.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: GWh out of a metered connection seems optimistic!

Comment: that's my average monthly use ~1GWh   Discount $ too with CV19

Comment: yes, total usage for the plant I am at is well into the GWh, but meters still do read in kWh.

Answer (score 1):

I work for an electric utility in the AMI group.  If you have 15 minute interval data from your electric meter, you can convert each 15 minute interval from kW to kWh by dividing by 4.

kW<sub>avg</sub>/4 = kWh.